# c strings unable to display (and maybe input)

Tags: c++, c-strings

I am stuck at this part of the code. The problem here is that the display from the console always cut off when I have yet to finish my input. Here is the code:

```
else if (m == 'c')
 {
  std::cout << "Enter the number of sentences used: ";
  int e;
  std::cin >> e;
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
  std::cout << "You've " << e << " number of sentences required to be filled.\n";
  char * f[e];
  for (int i = 0; i < e; i++)
  {
    std::cout << "Enter your " << i << " sentence: ";
    std::cin.getline (f[i], 99); //problem lies here
  };
  char * g = maxn (f, e);
  std::cout << "Your longest sentence is: " << g;
 }
```

There was no error or warning messages. It says normal termination. I thought it might be null/newline character affecting it but when I rectify it with clear() and ignore(), the result is still the same.

Is there any way to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the line

```
char * f[e];
```

declares a variable-sized array of pointers to `char`. This is not valid standard C++, but using a compiler extension. It is not recommended to use such compiler extensions, as they make your code un-portable.

Second, and most important, you are then trying to read with `getline` into these pointers, which *point to un-allocated memory*. This is wrong. You need to allocate memory for them,

```
char** f = new char*[e]; // now it's ok
for(int i = 0; i<e; ++i)
    f[e] = new char[99]; // allocate 99 bytes for each
```

Then, don't forget to delete them at the end of the program,

```
for(int i = 0; i<e; ++i)
    delete[] f[e];
delete[] f;
```

As you can see, it's pretty messy and error prone. It is much better to use standard library containers like `std::vector` and `std::string` that keep track of their memory and you'll use them almost as easily as fundamental types. If you want to go that route, then you should declare

```
std::vector<std::string> f(e); // must #include <vector> and #include <string>
```

instead, then read the sentences as

```
std::getline (std::cin, f[i]);
```

Of course you should also modify your functions that take/return `char*` to take/return `std::string`, but once you do this, your program will be much safer and easy to read/understand/debug.

In addition, after you're done reading with `cin` (and maybe validate the input), you need to `cin.ignore(...)`, since otherwise the newline is left in the buffer and its being "eaten" by the first `getline`.

This is how your code looks in modern C++, including the `cin` validation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the number of sentences used: ";
    int e;
    while(!(std::cin >> e)) // validate input
    {
        std::cin.clear(); // clear the error flags
        // discards everything else up to newline
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'); 
        std::cout << "Enter the number of sentences used: "; // repeat
    }
    std::cout << "You've " << e << " number of sentences required to be filled.\n";
    // IMPORTANT after cin and before getline
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n'); 
    std::vector<std::string> f(e); // our vector of sentences
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your " << i << " sentence: ";
        std::getline (std::cin, f[i]); 
    }
    auto it = std::max_element(f.begin(), f.end(), // this may look funky
        [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs)
        {
            return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
        }
    );
    std::cout << "Your longest sentence is: " << it->size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm using templates though, but I think I will use string instead of c-string.

Comment: If you know how to use templates, then you should definitely move away from C-strings, unless you really want some compatibility with some C stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give a value to an uninitialized pointer. That's what you're doing in `std::cin.getline (f[i], 99);`.

One solution would be to change the declaration from `char * f[e]` to `char f[e][99]`. Now `f` is initialized to *e* strings of 99 characters. And you can assign values to each of those strings with getline.